# What is the true range of a Bluetooth Device?

Tags: android

My Grandson,who is 12 and Autistic sent me a Bluetooth Message yesterday from his home more than a mile away. I had always believed that the range of a Bluetooth Device was about 50 ft. He used an I-Phone 4,and I have the Android MOTO-X PURE EDITION.I was very surprised because he does not read very well,nor spell very well. Yet,(not the 1st time he had a computer doing things I never thought of) he was able to send Bluetooth Messages from greater distances than I thought possible. Do these 2 Smart Phones have capabilities I,or we don't know about???

Comment: Bluetooth is not a messaging tech. You can't send a message through Bluetooth at all.

Comment: While it is possible to send a message over Bluetooth, it is unlikely that this was the medium used in this case (or at all, as the previous commenter suggests, there is no native way to send a simple message over bluetooth with either of these phones).  It was likely a instant messaging or SMS app.  What app did you open to view the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth specification says that guaranted range of Bluetooth link is 10m (line of sight), although it is possible to establish link over 100m. But to be honest I doubt he sent you message via Bluetooth, probably you had mistaken SMS or other messaging application.